# Can't install google cloud functions emulator

Tags: firebase, npm, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update firebase to the lastest version and encountered an error. That pointed me to the functions-emulator having an issue:

```
$ npm install @google-cloud/functions-emulator
npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."retry-request":"^4.0'
```

This happens after the recent update on firebase. Am I doing something wrong or is this bug I should report?

Tried multiple solutions including a complete de-install of npm, node and even vsc. Updating npm, trying to install the cloud functions emulator specifically...always the same error in some dependency file.

Here's the [error log](https://pastebin.com/R2ZESm7b)

```
88 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '..."retry-request":"^4.0'
```

I was just looking to update firebase to the latest version. Now everything is broken :D

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error occurred due to a corrupted file download (tried installing a firebase update on the train).

Solved with:

`npm cache clean --force`

Then re-installed package.